# Playing with object creation

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, factory, subclassing

I have two classes with method `foo`:

```
Foo = type('Foo', (object,), {'foo': lambda s: 'Foo method'})
Bar = type('Bar', (object,), {'foo': lambda s: 'Bar method'})
```

And I have some other class which I need to be subclassed of one of the above classes according to the parameter.

My Solution:

```
class Subject(object):
    def __new__(cls, key):
        base = (Foo if key else Bar)

        name = cls.__name__ + base.__name__
        dict_ = dict(cls.__dict__.items() + base.__dict__.items())
        bases = (base, cls)

        t = type(name, bases, dict_)
        return base.__new__(t)

    def bar(self):
        return 'Subject method'
```

Testing:

```
print(Subject(True).foo(), Subject(True).bar())
print(Subject(False).foo(), Subject(False).bar())
```

Output:

```
('Foo method', 'Subject method')
('Bar method', 'Subject method')
```

Is this solution safe enough? Or I need something more to know? Is there more pythonic way to do this kind of unregular stuff?

Comment: Make two classes, `SubjectFoo` and `SubjectBar`, inheriting from `Foo` and `Bar` respectively, and then write a function `Subject` that checks a parameter and returns an instance of the correct class. Much less likely to break in unexpected ways.

Comment: @ChrisLutz what unexpected ways can you see in my solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think most people would see the above code and recommend using composition rather than inheritance.  Subject would define a *foo* method that dispatched to the correct class based on the boolean value.

Alternatively, you could use a factory function to create either a Foo or Bar as needed.

```
def subject(selector):
     'Factory function that chooses between Foo and Bar'
     return Foo() if selector else Bar()
```

If needed, make both Foo and Bar inherit from a common class so that the factory function always returns an instance of a subclass of the common class.

Comment: some kind of `namedtuple` function?

Comment: I don't see the relationship to named tuples.

Answer (score 1):

If you avoid metaclasses (magic) the code will be more readable (and thus more pythonic). Go with the approaches suggested by Chris and Raymond, i.e.

use composition:

```
class Subject(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.foo = (Foo if key else Bar)().foo
    def bar(self):
        return 'Subject method'
```

or use a factory function:

```
def Subject(key):
    class Subject(Foo if key else Bar):
        def bar(self):
            return 'Subject method'
    return Subject()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of some unexpected behavior that could be caused by your current method, even if `Subject` overrides something from `Foo` or `Bar`, the `Foo` or `Bar` version of the method will be called:

```
class Subject(object):
    # all of your current methods as they were above
    def foo(self):
        return 'Subject foo'

>>> Subject(False).foo()
'Bar method'
```

Even though you could fix this by putting `base.__dict__.items()` before `cls.__dict__.items()` on the line where you create `dict_`, I would suggest moving away from this approach entirely, possibly using Chris Lutz' comment or [Raymond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959883/playing-with-object-creation/7959936#7959936).

If all you are interested in doing is having a dynamic method, I would suggest the following.  Create private versions of the methods inside of the `Subject` class, and then assign whichever method you want to use in `Subject.__init__()`:

```
class Subject(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.foo = self._Foo_foo if key else self._Bar_foo
    def _Foo_foo(self):
        return 'Foo method'
    def _Bar_foo(self):
        return 'Bar method'

>>> Subject(True).foo()
'Foo method'
>>> Subject(False).foo()
'Bar method'
```

Comment: I agree that the original metaclass approach is not the way to go.  A factory function or dynamic dispatch is the more traditional and predictable solution.